# If Function for multiple entries in Excel by multiplying cell with a certain value if they exceed or are below decided values

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I'm a begineer at excel so I was wondering if somebody could help me with this.

I have taken 2 cells, one with score and the other cell with the rate of score.

D Column ,  E Column  ,   F Column with certain values

Now I want a function ''IF'' in which F1 = D1 x 0.5 IF E1<50 or F1 = D1 x 0.8 IF 100>E1>50.0.1 Or If F1 = D1 x 1.1 If 150>E1.100.01    and so on....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it going as long as you want. Basically just put a comma at the end of the preceding line and not the last line.
Then put it on a new line to keep it readable (CTRL+ALT+ENTER on Windows)

An `IFS` is just a multiple conditional statement. You are comparing the first value, and doing the thing in the second one.

Then on the next line is another conditional statement.

```
=IFS(
E1<50, D1*0.5,
100>E1>=50, D1*0.8,
150>E1>=100, D1*1.1
)
```

Example.

```
=IFS(
test1,value1,
test2,value2,
test3,value3
)
```

[Resource](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-ifs-function)

Comment: Hi i made a new function and I Tried Doing This....................... =IFS(E9<30, D9*-3, 50> E9>=30, D9*-1, 75>E9>=50, D9*-0.2, 90>E9>=75,D9*0.4, 110>E9>=90,D9*0.7)  ............................ But it did not Work................. It Gave me an Error #NAME? .................... But still thanks for your answer :)